# How to write typescript with angularJs ?

Tags: typescript

How to write typescript with angularJs ? 
My html page using AngularJs is as below. 
**Index.cshtml:**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script> 
<html ng-app xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>    
 <title></title> 
</head> 
<body ng-app="helloang">
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>          
<div ng-controller="HelloName">       
  Your Name: <input type="text" ng-model="txtName" /><label>            
 your Address: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="chkboxAddress" ng-true-value="Kathmandu" ng-false-value="Nepal" />        
 </label>         <hr />       
  Hello {{txtName }}! <br />       
  Address = {{chkboxAddress}}   
  </div>  
</body> 
</html> 
<script>     
function HelloName($scope) {    
     $scope.txtName = 'World';   
      $scope.chkboxAddress = "Mention your address"; 
    } </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You javascript would work fine as valid JavaScript is valid TypeScript i.e. a `main.ts` file :

```
function HelloName($scope) {    
  $scope.txtName = 'World';   
  $scope.chkboxAddress = "Mention your address"; 
}
```

Of course you would compile this `.ts` file into a `.js` file before including with a script tag.

PS: Try to use a typescript class for easier scalability/maintainability of code.  here is a video on the subject : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E&hd=1

Comment: ok.. Thank you basarat.. and i watched a video too.. but typescript file is not recognizing static $inject, where else should be $inject defined plz tell me how to use it..

Comment: I don't understand, can you share the code sample, perhaps on : http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/